# QScrollArea: Scroll from item to item

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

Please consider the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Gallery(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedWidth(175)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        # Set widget and layout
        self._scroll_widget = QWidget()

        self._layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._layout.setSpacing(25)
        self._scroll_widget.setLayout(self._layout)

        self.setWidget(self._scroll_widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # Stretch
        self._layout.addStretch(1)  # Stretch above widgets
        self._layout.addStretch(1)  # Stretch below widgets

        # Initialize ---------------------------------|
        for _ in range(10):
            self.add_item()

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        # Calculate Margins --------------------|
        children = self._scroll_widget.findChildren(QLabel)
        first_widget = children[0]
        last_widget = children[-1]

        self._layout.setContentsMargins(
            0,
            int(event.size().height() / 2 - first_widget.size().height() / 2),
            0,
            int(event.size().height() / 2 - last_widget.size().height() / 2)
        )

    def add_item(self) -> None:
        widget = QLabel()
        widget.setStyleSheet('background: #22FF88')
        widget.setFixedSize(90, 125)

        child_count = len(
            self._scroll_widget.findChildren(QLabel)
        )
        self._layout.insertWidget(1 + child_count, widget,
                                  alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Gallery()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Currently, the margins of the layout are dynamically set, so that, no matter the size of the window, the first and last item are always vertically centered:

[image: Scrollbar containing multiple green rectangles, the first is vertically centered]

What I want to achieve now is that whenever I scroll (either by mousewheel or with the arrow-keys, as the scrollbars are disabled) the next widget should take the position in the vertical center, i.e. I want to switch the scrolling mode from a *per pixel* to a *per-widget*-basis, so that no matter how far I scroll, I will never land *between* two widgets.

How can this be done?

I found that [**QAbstractItemView**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) provides the option the switch the [ScrollMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollMode-enum) to *ScrollPerItem*, though I'm not sure if that's what I need because I was a bit overwhelmed when trying to subclass *QAbstractItemView*.

---

**Edit:**
This shows the delay I noticed after adapting **@musicamante**'s answer:

[image: GIF showing a short delay before the widgets are drawn]

It's not really disrupting, but I don't see it in larger projects, so I suppose something is not working as it should.

Comment: It's theoretically doable, but you probably need to use a subclass of QAbstractScrollArea. But, considering that you're disabling the scroll bars, there's no horizontal scrolling, and you require custom scrolling behavior, I believe that using a scroll area becomes actually pointless, and you might prefer to just subclass from a simple QWidget (or QFrame, if you want borders), add items as children and set their geometry manually by providing a generic "scrolling" function that can be called programmatically *and* from wheelEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the features QScrollArea provides are actually going to be ignored, subclassing from it doesn't give lots of benefits. On the contrary, it could make things much more complex.

Also, using a layout isn't very useful: the "container" of the widget is not constrained by the scroll area, and all features for size hinting and resizing are almost useless in this case.

A solution could be to just set all items as children of the "scroll area", that could be even a basic QWidget or QFrame, but for better styling support I chose to use a QAbstractScrollArea.

The trick is to compute the correct position of each child widget, based on its geometry. Note that I'm assuming all widgets have a fixed size, otherwise you might need to use their sizeHint, minimumSizeHint or minimum sizes, and check for their size policies.

Here's a possible implementation (I changed the item creation in order to correctly show the result):

```
from random import randrange

class Gallery(QAbstractScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedWidth(175)
        self.items = []
        self.currentIndex = -1

        for _ in range(10):
            widget = QLabel(str(len(self.items) + 1), 
                self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
            widget.setStyleSheet('background: #{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(
                randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255)))
            widget.setFixedSize(randrange(60, 100), randrange(50, 200))
            self.addItem(widget)

    def addItem(self, widget):
        self.insertItem(len(self.items), widget)

    def insertItem(self, index, widget):
        widget.setParent(self.viewport())
        widget.show()
        self.items.insert(index, widget)
        if len(self.items) == 1:
            self.currentIndex = 0
        self.updateGeometry()

    def setCurrentIndex(self, index):
        if not self.items:
            self.currentIndex = -1
            return
        self.currentIndex = max(0, min(index, len(self.items) - 1))
        self.updateGeometry()

    def stepBy(self, step):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.currentIndex + step)

    def updateGeometry(self):
        super().updateGeometry()
        if not self.items:
            return
        rects = []
        y = 0
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.items):
            rect = widget.rect()
            rect.moveTop(y)
            rects.append(rect)
            if i == self.currentIndex:
                centerY = rect.center().y()
            y = rect.bottom() + 25
        centerY -= self.height() / 2
        centerX = self.width() / 2
        for widget, rect in zip(self.items, rects):
            widget.setGeometry(rect.translated(centerX - rect.width() / 2, -centerY))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(175, 400)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QResizeEvent):
        self.updateGeometry()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() < 0:
            self.stepBy(1)
        else:
            self.stepBy(-1)
```

Comment: As always I learn a lot from your answers.

Just a small question: There seems to be a little "load-time" on startup where the window is just blank and I don't quite understand why, because it is independent of how many widgets are added.
What is happening there that takes so long?

Comment: Uhm, I don't see any of that, but to be fair I only tried it on Linux. What if you remove the `widget.show()` in `insertItem()`? Just to be sure, try to inherit from a simple QFrame instead of QAbstractScrollArea (this also means that reparenting is not on the viewport anymore, so the first line of `insertItem()` should be changed to `widget.setParent(self)`).

Comment: I tried to inherit from *QFrame*, but that didn't change it.  
I edited my answer to better show what's going on.

Comment: In any case, I cannot reproduce the issue as I don't use Windows, so it's a bit hard to understand what's going on there. It's obviously related to the transition effects of Windows, but I cannot tell you exactly where it comes from: I can only assume Windows tries to paint the widget before it's fully mapped, but without further debugging I really can't think of a solution.

Comment: I just noticed another problem (well, it's not really a problem since I didn't ask for it), but when I add a *QGraphicsOpacityEffect* to the widget like so: 
    *op_effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()*;
    *op_effect.setOpacity(.25)*;
    *self.setGraphicsEffect(op_effect)*;
the widgets get weirdly overlayed when scrolling because they're not properly redrawn. I'm not sure if this belongs here, but I'm unable to reproduce this in a MWE that would be unrelated to your answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by adding the effect to *self.viewport()* instead of *self*.